# Throttle and overheating on Dell XPS Studio 1645

Tags: laptop, overheating, fan, bios, dell-studio-xps-16

I realise there is an older thread on the very subject but that seems to be pretty dead.

I just got a Dell Studio XPS 1645 laptop and the fan noise and overheating is pretty ridiculous. This is actually a well known problem with the laptop that is apparently solved with the combination of a BIOS update and the purchase of their 130w charger. I plan on buying this charger as soon as possible, however I've noticed that since installing Ubuntu the fan noise has became more permanent and the overheating is quite a bit worse too. I've had to turn it off twice to let it cool down for an hour or so because it starts seriously affecting the performance. It makes watching things, listening to music or leaving the laptop on while I sleep a real pain.

If anyone has some new information on this issue or could help out in anyway at all I'd be very grateful. Thanks.

EDIT: I installed Windows to see if the problem was worsened by Ubuntu and sadly it seems so. It's still quite noisy but the temperatures are staying at a steady, much lower rate. Staying on Windows is something I'd definitely prefer not to do.

Comment: I have a noisy fan and my laptop overheats sometimes. but I solved it using `Jupiter`. what steps have you taken to solve the problem ? did you try debugging the acpi ? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingACPI

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a script to throttle your CPU frequency based on temperature. You set a max temperature, and if your system goes over that temperature it slows down your CPU(s).

http://seperohacker.blogspot.com/2012/10/linux-keep-your-cpu-cool-with-frequency.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: You go to the link and download a script to run that throttles CPU based on temperature. What essential parts am I leaving out?

Comment: As the meta post makes clear (http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) - if the website becomes unavailable, for whatever reason, the answer becomes worthless.  Thus either host the script here on AU or post on a public website such as launchpad or Github.

Comment: Thanks for that. After cooling down the laptop, booting up and running the script (I set it to 70 degrees) it doesn't seem to have had all that much effect. the computer is still very loud and very warm however it hasn't yet went into the 80+ temperatures in the 45 minutes since I ran the script. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Ah, thank you for clarifying that, ff. I don't want to post the code here because that page will always provide the most up to date version. I understand the concern, so I'll see what I can do.